# Undefined variable in django

Tags: python, django

I am a python newbie. i was trying out a django tutorial and got this error. I have two classes :

```
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length =300)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
    home_page = models.URLField(blank=True)
    summary = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    keywords = models.TextField(blank=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(**Category**,related_name="packages") //error line

class Category(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Package,related_name='categories')
    value = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
```

It gives me an undefined variable 'Category' error.Can somebody help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `Category` is not defined before `Package` is parsed.

Python parses the file from top to bottom. Therefore the `Category` class will not be defined when the `Packages`'s categories `ManyToManyField` relation is defined.

You can move `Category` class above the `Package` class, or enclose the relation in **quotes** so it's lazily loaded after class creation, like so:

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category',related_name="packages")
```

See the ForeignKey reference [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).